# How to get all child and sub child data into main parent data as a childData on loop in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, recursion

How to get all child and super-child data into main parent data as a childList as basic of `commentId` and `_id` on loop in an array of javascript recursion method.

If `commentId` is null means it's a parent data else `commentId` is same as another data's `_id` means it's a child of that item.

```
let Data = [
  {
    "comment": "P1.c1.s1.z1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-10T10:36:44.254+0000",
    "_id": 177,
    "commentId": 175,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1.c1.s1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:17.791+0000",
    "_id": 176,
    "commentId": 175,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1.c1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:07.097+0000",
    "_id": 175,
    "commentId": 172,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false,
    "isHaveChildComment": true
  },
  {
    "comment": "p2.c1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:55.963+0000",
    "_id": 174,
    "commentId": 173,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p2",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:48.146+0000",
    "_id": 173,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:41.066+0000",
    "_id": 172,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  }
]
```

final output need to be: all child and super child data need to be added into main parent data as childList of parent data whose commentId is null.

```
let finalOutput = [
  {
    "comment": "p2",
    "childList": [
      {
        "comment": "p2.c1",
        "upvoteCount": null,
        "downvoteCount": null,
        "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:55.963+0000",
        "_id": 174,
        "commentId": 173,
        "isUpvoted": false,
        "isDownvoted": null,
        "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
        "opid": 843,
        "opname": "king m",
        "isReplyClick": false
      }
    ],
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:48.146+0000",
    "_id": 173,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1",
    "ChildList": [
      {
        "comment": "p1.c1",
        "upvoteCount": null,
        "downvoteCount": null,
        "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:07.097+0000",
        "_id": 175,
        "commentId": 172,
        "isUpvoted": false,
        "isDownvoted": null,
        "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
        "opid": 843,
        "opname": "king m",
        "isReplyClick": false,
        "isHaveChildComment": true
      },
      {
        "comment": "p1.c1.s1",
        "upvoteCount": null,
        "downvoteCount": null,
        "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:17.791+0000",
        "_id": 176,
        "commentId": 175,
        "isUpvoted": false,
        "isDownvoted": null,
        "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
        "opid": 843,
        "opname": "king m",
        "isReplyClick": false
      },
      {
        "comment": "P1.c1.s1.z1",
        "upvoteCount": null,
        "downvoteCount": null,
        "createdDate": "2023-01-10T10:36:44.254+0000",
        "_id": 177,
        "commentId": 175,
        "isUpvoted": false,
        "isDownvoted": null,
        "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
        "opid": 843,
        "opname": "king m",
        "isReplyClick": false
      }
    ],
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:41.066+0000",
    "_id": 172,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  }
]
```

Comment: The question is very very unclear. Apparently you wish to map the `_id` as the id of the object and `commentId` as the id of its parent . But then in the expected output array you have the second object with `_id: 172`  and a prop `childList` including elements like `_id: 176, commentId: 175`. Why?

Comment: _id:176 is a super child data of (_id:172) so it's need to be added in parent data childList.(176's parent is 175 and 175's parent data is 172)

Comment: Try to embrace the word _minimal_ when creating your _minimal reproducible example_.  Do we really need to see all this cruft data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mapping objects to their ._id and getFurthestAncestor()

You may first have an object mapping each object found in the `data` array to its corresponding `_id` property value so that you'll have a criteria to filter items by furthest ancestor.

```
//maps the id to each object in objs
const mapById = objs.reduce((map, obj) => {map[obj._id] = obj; return map;}, {});

//returns the object being the furthest ancestor of the passed obj
function getFurthestAncestor(obj, mapById){        
  let parent = obj;
  while(parent.commentId !== null){    
    parent = mapById[parent.commentId];
  }  
  return parent._id;      
}
```

### Folding ancestors objects pushing their descendents in .descendents

Then you can just filter out the root elements (objects having `commentId` property as null) and on them add the `descendents` property as an array including all the elements having that corresponding furthest ancestor:

```
//returns the array of elements having .commentId == null
//(root elements with no parent)
const rootObjs = data.filter((obj) => obj.commentId === null);

//adds the property descendents to each objects in rootObjs
//valued with an array containing the list of descendents
const result = 
  rootObjs.map(rootObj => {
    rootObj['descendents'] = objs.filter(obj =>
      getFurthestAncestor(obj, mapById) === rootObj._id && obj._id != rootObj._id
    );
    return rootObj;
  });
```

### Demo

Here in this demo the entry point just runs as:

```
const result = getFoldedAncestors(data);
console.log( result );
```

And will print on console the object as what you expected in your question:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "comment": "P1.c1.s1.z1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-10T10:36:44.254+0000",
    "_id": 177,
    "commentId": 175,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1.c1.s1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:17.791+0000",
    "_id": 176,
    "commentId": 175,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1.c1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:26:07.097+0000",
    "_id": 175,
    "commentId": 172,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false,
    "isHaveChildComment": true
  },
  {
    "comment": "p2.c1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:55.963+0000",
    "_id": 174,
    "commentId": 173,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": "king m",
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p2",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:48.146+0000",
    "_id": 173,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  },
  {
    "comment": "p1",
    "upvoteCount": null,
    "downvoteCount": null,
    "createdDate": "2023-01-09T12:25:41.066+0000",
    "_id": 172,
    "commentId": null,
    "isUpvoted": false,
    "isDownvoted": null,
    "repliedCommentUserName": null,
    "opid": 843,
    "opname": "king m",
    "isReplyClick": false
  }
];


const result = getFoldedAncestors(data);
console.log( result );

//returns the object being the furthest ancestor of the passed obj
function getFurthestAncestor(obj, mapById){        
  let parent = obj;
  while(parent.commentId !== null){    
    parent = mapById[parent.commentId];
  }  
  return parent._id;      
}

//returns an array of objs with ancestors on top and descendents as items of their descendents prop
function getFoldedAncestors(objs){

  //maps the id to each object in data
  const mapById = objs.reduce((map, obj) => {map[obj._id] = obj; return map;}, {});

  //returns the array of elements having .commentId == null (root elements with no parent)
  const rootObjs = data.filter((obj) => obj.commentId === null);

  //adds the property descendents to each objects in rootObjs with the list of descendents
  const result = 
    rootObjs.map(rootObj => {
      rootObj['descendents'] = objs.filter(obj =>
        getFurthestAncestor(obj, mapById) === rootObj._id && obj._id != rootObj._id
      );
      return rootObj;
    });
  
  return result;
}
```